# Photos album disappear when start scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a photos album, with around 40 small photos on mobile.

I do it with :

```
for(let k=0; k<data.length; k++) {
    var item = $(".item").first().clone();
    item.removeClass("hidden").find(".itemimg").attr("src",data[k].image);
    $(".listings").append(item);
     item.on('click', function (){
     .......
}
```

and `HTML` :

```
<div class="listings">
   <div class="item hidden">
      <img class="itemimg">
      <img class="checkeditem hidden" src="images/checked.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

On `Chrome` `simulator` it works, but on *actual* device ( iPhone Safari) , I see the first 4 photos , and the photos that hidden (overflow) will not show when i scroll. I can only see the container of them, but not the photos.
**When i click on a photo (the background, I don't see it's photo), then all visible elements will appear again.**

Is this a memory problem ? how to properly load this list ?

**EDIT**:

```
.listings{
  width: 94%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 2vh;
}
.item{
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
  height: 30vh;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
  border-radius: 3vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;

}
.itemimg{
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `.listings { overflow-y: auto; }` to css?

Comment: thanks, yes it didn't work. When i scroll i see nothing, BUT, when i click an item, they all appear suddenly !

Answer (score 1):

Have no idea why, but removing this :

```
  overflow: hidden;
```

from my `item` `CSS`, solved the problem.